# using model forms to save data in different databases

Tags: python, django

Ok the problem is that I have a model in which a field is unique. I am inputting that field value from user in post body and wanted to save that via model form in a database that is also specified in post body.

```
# models.py
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#forms.py
class TypeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Type
        fields = "__all__"

# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': "default",
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'abcd1234',
        'HOST': '0.0.0.0',
        "PORT": "3306"
    },
    'database1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': "database1",
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'abcd1234',
        'HOST': '0.0.0.0',
        "PORT": "3306"
    },
}

#views.py
def index(request):
    db_name=request.POST["db_name"]
    ob = TypeCreateForm(request.POST)
    for a in ob:
        if a.errors:
            print(a.errors.as_text())

    ob=ob.save(commit=False)
    ob.save(using=db_name)
```

I searched several similar question of saving into another database other than default.Some suggested `commit=False` will work along with save with using keyword argument.

In some answer they suggested to do modification in queryset of the field.
But I dont think that worked for me because in my model there is a unique constraint as well so when I will print the errors before saving it will show unique constraint failed if that type is stored in default db even if I might want to save in the second database.

Isn't there any way that I can make such that while initiating a form object I also specify the db name and it will save into that db and errors will also come corresponding to that selected db

Also I cant use `Type.objects.using(db_name).create()`
because I may add validations as well later that can only be checked via forms.