# Specific DB Access Query Optimisation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
In [14]: from accounts.models import CustomUser

In [15]: CustomUser.objects.filter()
Out[15]: <QuerySet [<CustomUser: nimish4july1998@gmail.com,Nimish,(9)>, <CustomUser: company1@gmail.com,Escale,(10)>, <CustomUser: adv1@gmail.com,advertiser1,(16)>, <CustomUser: adv2@gmail.com,,(17)>, <CustomUser: adv3@gmail.com,,(18)>, <CustomUser: adv4@gmail.com,,(19)>, <CustomUser: adv5@gmail.com,,(20)>, <CustomUser: ok@gmail.com,,(33)>, <CustomUser: pub_company1@gmail.com,,(34)>, <CustomUser: ,,(35)>, <CustomUser: employee1@gmail.com,,(40)>, <CustomUser: employeeno1@gmail.com,,(41)>, <CustomUser: adv500@gmail.com,,(42)>]>



In [17]: CustomUser.objects.using("company1")
Out[17]: <QuerySet [<CustomUser: nimish4july1998@gmail.com,Nimish,(9)>, <CustomUser: company1@gmail.com,Escale,(10)>, <CustomUser: adv1@gmail.com,advertiser1,(16)>, <CustomUser: adv2@gmail.com,,(17)>, <CustomUser: adv3@gmail.com,,(18)>, <CustomUser: adv4@gmail.com,,(19)>, <CustomUser: adv5@gmail.com,,(20)>, <CustomUser: ok@gmail.com,,(33)>, <CustomUser: pub_company1@gmail.com,,(34)>, <CustomUser: ,,(35)>, <CustomUser: employee1@gmail.com,,(40)>, <CustomUser: employeeno1@gmail.com,,(41)>, <CustomUser: adv500@gmail.com,,(42)>]>



In [18]: CustomUser.objects
Out[18]: <django.db.models.manager.Manager at 0x7ff0906fa1d0>
```

So my question is that when we want to use a specific db as soon as we apply function using() we see the whole queryset.On the other hand using it normally like CustomUser.objects it doesnot return queryset unless we apply filter

so does that mean for a specific database we are able to see the whole queryset and then we have to apply filter will not make query fast.Actually I am confused that will there be any difference if there are same no of records in "default db" and "company1 db" and exactly same data,
will one query be faster than the second or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no difference here. `using` returns a queryset, just like `all`. You can filter on either of them without executing the query until you iterate it.

Comment: oh kk thank you.Can you also help regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899376/using-model-forms-to-save-data-in-different-databases :-)